# Paste X flipped post not working correctly

Tags: rigging

I have made a character in blender and rigged it and happy with it. But for animation, I find that *Paste x flipped pose* is very much necessary for various animations like walk cycle, run cycle, etc. I named all the bones with the correct suffix ('.L' and '.R'). *Paste x flipped pose* works, but not as I am expecting. Where could I be wrong in rigging?

[image: The original pose]

[image: Wrong X flipped pose]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every bone .L should have a bone roll value equal and negative to the corresponding .R.
Set a front ortographic view, select the armature, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> (Apply rotation and scale), go to edit mode, select all bones, <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> (recalculate roll - view axis).
This procedure will make the flip pose possible, but it will break all the previously done animations.

Comment: <kbd> tags around keyboard keys please. E.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: <kbd>OK, OK<kbd>

Comment: wish I had known this BEFORE. Where can I read more about this? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this chat: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?319227-Bone-roll-explanation-please